# Determine Hive version via query

Tags: hive

With Apache Drill I can get the version through a JDBC connection by dispatching the query: `SELECT version FROM sys.version`. Is there an analogous way to determine the Hive version?

I know I can use `hive --version` from a machine where Hive is running and available via the command line. However a query-based approach would fit my use case a little better as JDBC connections may be made from anywhere inside my network.

Comment: Drill directly works with Hive MetaStore, I not sure if its possible to get Hive version.

Comment: I really was just using drill to illustrate what I'm after. I'd like to do something similar to what I can already do with drill using just hive. I haven't found any way to discover a version via some query yet though.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you have a JDBC Connection.

```
Connection conn = // get it from somewhere
DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetadata();
System.out.println(md.getDatabaseMajorVersion() + "." + md.getDatabaseMinorVersion());
```

I don't know if you can get the information from a SQL/HiveQL query.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this query

```
select version();
```